# What does 'otherwise' mean here?

Tags: meaning

"hospitality industry includes... restaurants operated in or in connection with premises owned or operated by employers otherwise covered by this award"

What does the word 'otherwise' mean here?

1) Does it mean employers not covered by this award

2) Does it mean employers covered by this award

link: (under clause 4.2) https://www.fwc.gov.au/documents/documents/modern_awards/award/ma000009/default.htm

Comment: Yes, it means covered *in other ways*. Consider that crosswise means in crossed ways.

Comment: I find the use of "otherwise" superfluous there. It means "in any other way". The award is granted to employers meeting certain requirements, and "hospitality industry" is said to include premises owned or operated by employers who are covered by the grant pursuant to the terms stipulated elsewhere.